# sqlite3 .execute2 snagging in a ruby file

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have the following sqlite code as a standalone file.  It works.
the schema is basic.  `foo.db` table `bar`  `Id`, `Text`, `Value`, `Etc` are my columns

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sqlite3'
puts "enter a number"
input = gets.chomp.to_i
begin
    db = SQLite3::Database.open('foo.db')
    find_data = db.execute2 "select * from bar where Value = #{input}"
    find_data.each do |f|
        puts "[%-8s] %-8s | %-8s" % [f[1], f[2], f[3]]
    end
rescue SQLite::Exception => e
    puts e
ensure
    db.close if db
end
```

`execute2` locates the line and `find_data.each` prints out.

However when I take the above snippet and place into a method in a larger program, I get `no such column: [input]"

In my method. **I have condensed the code**:

```
...
def find_info(info)
    begin
        db = SQLite3::Database.open('foo.db')
        puts db.get_first_value "select SQLite_VERSION()"
        return "create a directory first" unless File.exist?('foo.db')
        #line below does not work at print_out below
        print_out = db.execute2 "SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE Value=#{info}"
        #but making the following changes works:
        #info_in = info; print_out = db.execute2 "select * from BAR WHERE Value = :info_in", info_in
        return "no match" unless print_out != nil
        print_out.each do |line|
            puts "[%-8s] %-8s | %-8s" % [line[1], line[2], line[3]]
        end
    rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
        puts e
    ensure
        db.close if db
    end
end
...

print 'enter text to search for'
info = gets.chomp.to_s
X.NewInstance.new; X.find_info(info)
```

*My question:* Why am I obligated to use a placeholder in `print_out`?  I believe I should be able just throw in a variable as `print_out = db.execute2 "select * from Bar WHERE Value=#{info}"`

please help.  I am dumbfounded.

(Also: there must be a way on SO to indent blocks of code most efficiently than hitting 4 spaces for each line of code...I spend more time formatting the code than I do typing the question...pls advise?)

Comment: You not doing any quoting on your `info` at all; you're doing `input = gets.chomp.to_i` in the first case so it works okay because you always end up with a number but in the second case you're saying `info = gets.chomp.to_s` so you have a string. Look into prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: As far as formatting goes, there's a `{}` button in the toolbar so you can select a block of text and hit that button. You could also read the [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) documentation that the editor's toolbar links too.

Comment: @muistooshort in this instance input is a variable #{var} should be sufficient?

Comment: No, raw string interpolation works only by accident. Always use placeholders or (if absolutely necessary) the driver's quoting methods.

Comment: @muistooshort ok my concern with placeholders is 1) extra lines of repetition in code (eg var1 = var)   and 2) leads lengthy code (eg: db.execute "update TABLEX SET moo= :something where moo = :something_else", something something_else.   *Any instance when string interpolation* would work with INTENT?

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation fails in this instance.  Placeholders can be utilized.

```
print_out = db.execute2 "select * from BAR WHERE Value = :info", info
print_out.each do |p|
    puts "%s %s %s" % [p[1],p[2],p[3]]
end
```